# Is NSWindow on OS X the same as UIView on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have been an iOS dev since iOS3. I have decided to give Mac development a try, but I am running into quite a few differences. So I have a couple of questions.

1. Is an NSWindow == UIView on iOS? and if so, what is the controller class? (i.e. UIViewController).
2. Does anyone know of some good tutorials for a mac dev coming from an iOS background? Google is not helping today.

Comment: There is `NSView` but because "documents" are so important in most OSX applications, the normal controller structure is different.  I don't have a tutorial handy, but here's a document that covers some of what you're asking: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/KeyObjects/KeyObjects.html

Comment: Fundamentally, NSWindow has no equivalent on OSX, because iOS apps are inherently single-window.

Answer (score 2):

An [NSWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is not identical to a [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) (an [NSView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) is closer to a UIView). Have a look at the linked developer documentation to get a feel for the differences.

When I went from iOS to OS X I got myself a copy of [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0321774086) (Amazon UK link) by Hillegass and Preble. I skipped the first part about basics of Objective-C and concentrated on the UI differences mainly. NSTableViews in particular are far different from UITableViews. After a few days I knew enough to get started on my own apps and use the book more like a reference.

Also, the developer documentation is your Bible. I downloaded the [DocSets](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/docsets/id509945577?mt=8) app ($4.99 App Store link - [also available on GitHub](https://github.com/omz/DocSets-for-iOS)) to view it on my iPad and have it beside my Macbook when developing at all times.

Comment: I am wondering where I get my delegate methods - (void)viewDidLoad. is there an equivalent?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is a method of `UIViewController`, not `UIView`. The equivalents on OS X would be `NSWindowController` and `NSViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the developer site. For example there is [Start Developing Mac Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/chapters/01_Introduction.html).

You know Objective-C, the Cocoa philosophy and the the development environment. So you'll progress through this very quickly and you'll see the differences easily. It's a basic tutorial walkthrough - but there are plenty of links to related sections that you can read about.

Keep an eye out for Cocoa Bindings - which aren't on iOS, but are very useful for writing desktop apps.

**Following up from a comment on another answer**

Unlike iOS where there is only one window on the screen but many views, desktop uses more windows. Thinking in terms of the iOS Views and Controllers paradigm is going to be limiting. Have a look at the [Windows Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000031i) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of 2.

You can refer many sites, I would like to share my learning process with you.

I started learning with these...

Stanford lectures CS193

Lynda's Videos

Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X by Aaron Hillegas

Cocoadevcentral.com

Last one is of course Stack Overflow... This is the best place to sort out all your doubts.